# How to use checked exceptions in a visitor pattern

Tags: java, exception, visitor-pattern

Suppose I have a suite of classes that accept a visitor (visitor-pattern), but due to the nature of those classes or a particular visitor, performing working on them will likely be capable of throwing a checked exception.

The visitor-accepting interface:

```
public interface Mammal
{
    void accept(MammalVisitor visitor);
}
```

The visitor interface:

```
public interface MammalVisitor
{
    void visit(Cat m);
    void visit(Dog m);
    void visit(Cow m);
}
```

And the implementations of Mammal:

```
public class Cat implements Mammal
{
    public void accept(MammalVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

We'll assume Dog & Cow are implemented identical to Cat

Now suppose my visitor is:

```
public class MammalPrinter implements MammalVisitor
{
    private final Appendable out;

    public MammalPrinter(Appendable out)
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Cat m)
    {
        out.append("I'm a cat");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Dog m)
    {
        out.append("I'm a dog");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Cow m)
    {
        out.append("I'm a cow");
    }
}
```

And I print the result to stdio:

```
Mammal m = MammalFactory.getMammal();
MammalPrinter mp = new MammalPrinter(System.out);
m.accept(mp);
```

However, MammalPrinter above is *syntactically incorrect*, because Appendable.append(String) throws `java.io.IOException`.  I can't declare the throw on each visit method, because it is not declared in the visitor interface.

The solutions I've considered:

- Declare `throws IOException` on `Mammal.accept()`, all three `MammalVisitor.visit()`, and all three `MammalPrinter.visit()`

  - Very unsavoury: the Mammal and MammalVisitor interfaces are now *aware* of their potential usage involving IO, which is contrary to the whole point of using the visitor-pattern.
- Declare `throws Throwable` on `Mammal.accept()` and all three `MammalVisitor.visit()`, and declare `throws IOException` on all three `MammalPrinter.visit()`

  - Better than the above solution: Mammal and MammalVisitor are now *usage agnostic*.  However, they are also now unwieldy to use: visitors that throw no exceptions are still forced to handle Throwable from the accept() method.

I have two other solutions that I favour over the above, with which I will self-answer my post.  I'd like to see which one is favoured by the community at large.

Comment: Aren't the visitors already aware they are doing IO by calling Appendable.append? Appendable is what declares the exception as thrown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was going to mention the unchecked wrapped re-throw approach, but Giodude beat me to it.  Instead, I'll suggest another approach that I call the *courtesy exception* (because it is integrated in the interfaces as a courtesy to implementers).

When designing the visitor and Mammal interfaces, I outfit them to handle one exception of the user's choosing.  The visitor:

```
public interface MammalVisitor<T extends Throwable>
{
    void visit(Cat m) throws T;
    void visit(Dog m) throws T;
    void visit(Cow m) throws T;
}
```

And Mammal:

```
public interface Mammal
{
    <T extends Throwable> void accept(MammalVisitor<T> visitor) throws T;
}
```

And the implementation of Mammal:

```
public class Cat implements Mammal
{
    @Override
    public <T extends Throwable> void accept(MammalVisitor<T> visitor) throws T
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Dog and Cow are implemented identically.  And the printing visitor:

```
public class MammalPrinter implements MammalVisitor<IOException>
{
    private final Appendable out;

    public MammalPrinter(Appendable out)
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Cat m) throws IOException
    {
        out.append("I'm a cat");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Dog m) throws IOException
    {
        out.append("I'm a dog");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Cow m) throws IOException
    {
        out.append("I'm a cow");
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
Mammal m = MammalFactory.getMammal();
MammalPrinter mp = new MammalPrinter(System.out);
try
{
    m.accept(mp);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("An IOException occurred");
}
```

Which results in a much more intuitive and easy to implement usage from the end-user's perspective.

With this pattern, if a visitor does not have a checked exception to throw, they specify some unchecked exception as the generic in their implementation:

```
public class MammalPrinter implements MammalVisitor<RuntimeException>
{
```

When Mammal.accept() is called with the above visitor, no catching is needed to be syntactically correct.  Perhaps you could further increase readability by making an extend of RuntimeException called "NeverThrown" that has a private constructor.

Comment: Before someone suggests: yes, you could add more than one generic type parameter to the interfaces to support more than one exception.  This treads too close to *usage expectations* (read: *not agnostic*) for my liking.  At least with one, you have the benefit of wrapping (like @Giodude suggests), but instead of an unchecked exception that might fall through the syntax cracks, you can use a checked exception which syntactically must be dealt with by the caller.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it. I feel like it would end up getting messy though. Another option is to have throw a checked exception of some user defined exception class. However, the perception of checked exception as being a failed experiment in the Java language is very pervasive in the community, so I wouldn't recommend them in general.

Comment: This pattern is to lend aid to coders who embrace (and rely) on checked exceptions.

Comment: I understand that. If I want to have checked exception, I'd rather have my own hierarchy of exceptions so that my methods all throw the same type of exception and I don't have to resort to generics. Besides, what if you want to throw both IOException and SQLException? Now you must necessarily use Exception as your type parameter, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Very true... for more than one exception, you're back to wrapping; but at least you can wrap with a checked exception so it's more clear that something needs handling from the accept() call.  For one exception however, which is probably the most common case, the developer using the hierarchy and its visitor has a very intuitive way of throwing and handling their checked exception.  In your case, you'd simply use the top exception in your application's own hierarchy and be done with it.

Comment: I like the idea, just wish Java's type parameters (aka, "generics") syntax didn't make it so ugly.

Comment: I'm wondering if the same concept can be applied to allowing the Visitor to return objects from it's visit methods. I realize that's not typically part of Visitor implementations, but I'm currently facing a situation where I need to accumulate results from nested Visitors, and having return values would be useful.

Comment: @E-Riz To return objects from `visit()`, I would recommend storing them in local fields of the visitor class instance.

Comment: `courtesy exception`.  Thanks for documenting this pattern!

Comment: It is quite aged topic, but still valid I guess. I was hit by this issue just today.
The problem with the pattern you suggest is that it cannot cover situation when the implementing code throws multiple checked exceptions. 
Imagine that the code inside method visit() throws an IOException and also an InterruptedException.

Answer (score 5):

You could catch the checked exceptions and throw them wrapped in unchecked exceptions. See for example how Spring converts JDBC or JMS checked exceptions to unchecked ones.

Comment: Preferably a custom unchecked exception.

Comment: Can you take a look at my solution below, and share your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an option which is to internally handle the IOException. Options are to ignore it, report it, or rethrow it wrapped as a RuntimeException....

```
// Ignore it (swallow it).
@Override 
public void visit(Cow m) {
    try {
        out.append("I'm a cow");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // swallow this exception - it will never happen
    }
}

// report it
@Override 
public void visit(Cow m) {
    try {
        out.append("I'm a cow");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// wrap and rethrow it.
@Override 
public void visit(Cow m) {
    try {
        out.append("I'm a cow");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to append to output", ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: For separation of concern, the visitor does only one thing: print the name of the mammal to some Appendable.  It is not aware of what sort of stream to which it is printing (or if it is capable of throwing), nor what to do in the case of an exception.  The intent is to let the Mammal.accept() caller handle any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on whether you want your client code to be impacted by those exceptions or not.  You could swallow them within the code, wrap them in Runtime Exceptions as above, or alternatively you could add throws Exception to the 'visit' methods and do something with it or rethrow it in the accept method.

Doing the last option would be acknowledging that whatever the visitor does has the capacity to create an exception condition and that calling code should be aware of that.

Comment: The intent is that the visitor only does one thing: append a string that represents the type of Mammal.  It is not aware of the type of stream to which it's appending, nor assumes any behavioural response to exceptions, aside from communicating directly to the caller in some way.